# Track existing folder from remote git repo

Tags: git, github

Somehow the `.git` folder got deleted from my project folder. My project folder may contain changes which I don't know of. Maybe it can be older than the remote version on GitHub.

Is there a way I can start tracking everything again so that I can run `git status` to see the changes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create the `.git` folder in your project folder by :

```
$ git init
```

Then you can add and commit all the files you wish :

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -m 'some comment'
```

Then you add the remote repository (the exact command depends on your project name in GitHub and your credentials to access it) :

```
$ git remote add origin git@gitserver:/opt/git/project.git
```

Now you can do `git fetch` to get all the branches from the remote version, and decide what to do with them.